# Encrypting a Sqlite database accessed through Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, sqlcipher

I need to encrypt the sqlite database of the iOS application I'm developing. I managed to do that with SQLCipher library. In my application this database is queried through Core Data. I do not understand if it is possible to tell Core Data to use the unencrypted version (obtained with SQLCipher) of the database. Is it possible? 
If not, what do I have to do? How to encrypt the database and tell Core Data to unencrypt it and to use unencrypted info? I read many other posts, but they are not much useful. 
NB: the sqlite database is in the documents folder of the iOS app, and my purpose is to deny access to the data to any user.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Core Data with SQLCipher, you will want to check out the [encrypted-core-data](https://github.com/project-imas/encrypted-core-data) project.

Comment: Yeah, I checked out and tried to integrate it with my app, but I cannot figure out how to make it work. I followed the tutorial in the page you linked, I hooked up the EncryptedStore to my database, but executing NSFetchRequests on the NSManagedObjectContext obtained from the coordinator return always 0 results.